# Override screen size in linux telnet

Tags: telnet

Here's my predicament. I'm developing a perl telnet script that uses Expect to spawn a new telnet process and feed data (non-interactively) into it.

Everything works fine when I call the script from a terminal - however, if I start the script from cron I am unable to login to the remote device because the Window size negociation fails - as my client sends a window size of 0x0 (instead of 80x24).

Apparently telnet gets this window size from its master PTY - which isn't a TTY if it's called from cron. Most likely telnet is getting these settings using ioctl or some similar mechanism, because trying to override these settings by environment variables failed (*ROWS=200 COLUMNS=80 telnet test*).

I ran stty from cron and redirected the output to a file. Problem is stty complains when it's run from cron: */bin/stty: standard input: Invalid argument*

Do you know any way to:
1) override the number of rows/columns telnet sends to the remote device
2) start a tty and start telnet inside that tty (from cron)

Thanks

Comment: update - I managed to solve my problem by using a workaround. The expect module has a function which copies the size of a TTY to the current "TTY" in which telnet runs. Problem was the default TTY was STDIN -  which has no dimensions when run from cron. I forced it to get its dimensions from /dev/tty0 instead:<br>
<b>
#we're running from cron or smth <br>
$logger->debug("setting /dev/tty0 window size to 80x24:");</br>
`/bin/stty -F /dev/tty0 columns 80 rows 24`;<br>
open TTY0, "/dev/tty0" or die "Can't open /dev/tty0: $!";<br>
</b>
    $session->slave->clone_winsize_from(\*TTY0);

Comment: You've accepted an answer after 7.5 years! With it, you a record holder of this site!

Comment: :) Yeah. I stumbled on my question 7 years later and I had to agree with myself in the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

update - I managed to solve my problem by using a workaround. The expect module has a function which copies the size of a TTY to the current "TTY" in which telnet runs. Problem was the default TTY was STDIN -  which has no dimensions when run from cron. I forced it to get its dimensions from /dev/tty0 instead:

#we're running from cron or smth 
$logger->debug("setting /dev/tty0 window size to 80x24:");
 `/bin/stty -F /dev/tty0 columns 80 rows 24`;
open TTY0, "/dev/tty0" or die "Can't open /dev/tty0: $!";
$session->slave->clone_winsize_from(*TTY0);

Answer (score 1):

I found this post very useful as I ran into the same problem after migrating some Perl code away from using Net::Telnet to Expect (Expect has extremely useful debugging output in comparison).

However in my situation I had a /dev/tty0 that was pretty locked down (only root could read it) and I didn't want to change that:

```
crw--w----    1 root     tty        4,   0 Aug 30  2002 /dev/tty0
```

I looked at the Expect/IO::Pty/IO::Tty source and ended up hacking in the following - which essentially does the same thing (80 x 24) without needing to read from /dev/tty0.

```
use IO::Tty;
use IO::Tty::Constant;
my $winsize = pack('SSSS', 24, 80, 0, 0);
ioctl($exp->slave(), &IO::Tty::Constant::TIOCSWINSZ, $winsize);
```

Answer (score 0):

In the start of the script:

```
set columns 80
set rows 24
```